# Must a child of a template class also be a template class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-c++, inheritance

I'm required to have a class "LinkedSortedList" that is a child of "SortedList". SortedList is a template class, so how can I have a child that isn't also a template? The only issue here is that I need to have both LinkedSortedList.h and .cpp, but apparently you cannot leave the definitions for a template in a .cpp, they must be defined with the method/function declarations inside the .h, so I wouldn't have a LinkedSortedList.cpp....or am I just being a complete idiot?

Answer (score 2):

Well lets assume that your `LinkedSortedList` is only to work with type `int` (otherwise it would need to be a template it self).

First the compiler needs to know that `SortedList<int>` must be compiled at the time when `sorted_list.cpp` (or whereever the template is implemented) is available. Once it is compiled the linker will find it and be able to successfully link it.

So in `linked_sorted_list.h` you would have something like:

```
#include "sorted_list.h"

class LinkedSortedList : public SortedList<int> {
   ...
}
```

In `sorted_list.cpp`, at the end you must include this line:

```
template class SortedList<int>;
```

Alternatively (and that is the better way) you can put the definition of the template into a file with special extention (I tend to you use `.icc`) that gets included in `sorted_list.h`:

```
template <class type>
class SortedList { 
   ...
}

#include "sorted_list.icc"
```

Now you can compile any types of sorted lists on the fly.

Comment: Explicit instantiation is done with `template class SortedList<int>;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only derive from a fully-defined class, not a class template.  This means the code

```
    template <class C>
    struct A{};
    struct B : public A{};
```

is invalid.  However, both

```
    struct B : public A<int>{};
    template <class C>
    struct B : public A<C>{};
```

are valid.  So it looks like you'll be stuck with templates.  If you *really* want to have a .cpp file you can move your code into a .cpp and then include it in your .h file (after your class definition).  I don't really recommend it because (IMO) it obfuscates your code.

Comment: You can define the body of template methods outside of the class definition as follows:

template <class T>
class Printer {
   void print();
};

template <class T>
void Printer::print() { ... }

It is common to put these definitions in a separate file, and they _must_ be included at the end of your header. Since they are not compiled, the typical naming convention for the inline definitions of foo.h is foo_inl.h

Comment: I realize you can define your member functions outside your class body, but I've never seen them defined in a separate file.  I guess it's not unreasonable to do, just a matter of preference really