# C++ Header and Source Directories

Tags: c++, gcc, directory-structure, undefined-reference

I have the following files:

```
listDriverTest.cpp
src/List.cpp
headers/List.h
```

The include in List.cpp is

```
#include "../headers/List.h"
```

The include in listDriverTest.cpp is

```
#include "headers/List.h"
```

When I compile with the following statement,

```
g++ listDriverTest.cpp "src/List.cpp"
```

I end up with a fair number of 'undefined reference' errors, e.g.

```
listDriverTest.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `List<int>::List()'
listDriverTest.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `List<int>::add(int)'
listDriverTest.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `List<int>::add(int)'
...
```

How should I properly use includes and compile these three files in order for the compilation to work properly?  I have gotten listDriverTest.cpp to compile and run properly with all the files in the same directory, but not when they're broken up like this.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a very specific error related to the inability to find the list.h header.

Comment: You need to define everything in header file when working with templates http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13

Comment: *Undefined reference* are linker errors, so it has few to nothing to do with your header/source locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer in [Must a child of a template class also be a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10082225/1238764).

It is probably a different question, but the same answer applies.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I /completely/ forgot about the issue with having a header file and cpp file for template methods that belong to a class.  That fixed the problem right up!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the object file produced by compiling src/List.cpp already contains the specialization List, but it's in a different directory than the object file of listDriversTest.cpp. Hence, the linker cannot find it.

Of course, this depends on how you've organized your template code.

Answer (score 0):

Your program compiled properly on my machine. 
Just remove the double quotes around src/List.cpp
I think your problem is something else.

I added a function void list(void) in list.cpp which printed "list". 
The same signature was added to list.h.